# Client side validations using the hibernate validtor

Tags: hibernate, validation

In a spring project which is using  the hibernate Validator is there a way to specify client side validations using the hibernate Validator ? if possible is it possible without annotations.
The view technology is jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate validator (and JSR-349) can be used in different layers of your app. Since you didn't provide any information about the client technology you are using it's difficult to say more than *read the doc* [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-integration).